# Get complete cases of data frame based on formular

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, missing-data

I have a data frame with panel data and I would like to get all complete observations based on a formular.

While extracting the variables from the formula is pretty straightforward (using get_all_vars), I would also like to incorporate things like lags (in this case from the dplyr-package) in formulas.

Let's take the formular:

```
y ~ x1 + lag(x2, 1) + lag(x3, 2)
```

and the data frame

```
  y    x1  x2   x3
1 2    3   NA   NA 
2 3    2   2    2  
3 2    6   5    3  
4 5    8   6    9 
5 1    3   7    4 
6 1    0   1    2
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
  y    x1  x2   x3
1 2    3   NA   NA 
2 3    2   NA   NA  
3 2    6   2    NA  
4 5    8   5    2 
5 1    3   6    3 
6 1    0   7    9
```

In the end I want to use this to create dummies for the different time periods (and since my panel is unbalanced and for some years no case is complete, creating them for all periods does not work).

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can use `model.matrix` instead `get_all_vars`.  `model.matrix( ~ y + x1 + lag(x2, 1) + lag(x3, 2), data = df)`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I want. First, I need to rewrite the formula (otherwise I don't get y), second, I would like to have the whole data including the cases with NAs. Otherwise it is not that straightforward to bind the column with the years to the data set and create the dummies based on that.
Additional question:
Does this take care of the panel structure? E.g. when it comes to lags.

Comment: In that case, the only way I think of is to create a new variable for each of the terms in the formula.

Comment: Hm? What do you mean?

Comment: Where is `lag` coming from? `dplyr`? Are we supposed to provide an answer that will support any function form any package there is? You should show all your dependencies and try be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's coming from dplyr. An answer supporting this type of lag-function would be enough (if there's a more general answer it might help more people).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can accomplish your example output given you sample input using `model.frame`

```
my_df <- read.table(text=" y    x1  x2   x3
                         1 2    3   NA   NA 
                         2 3    2   2    2  
                         3 2    6   5    3  
                         4 5    8   6    9 
                         5 1    3   7    4 
                         6 1    0   1    2 ", header=T)

out_df <- model.frame(y ~ x1 + dplyr::lag(x2, 1) + dplyr::lag(x3, 2), 
                      data=my_df,
                      na.action=NULL)
names(out_df) <- names(my_df)
out_df

#output
    y x1 x2 x3
  1 2  3 NA NA
  2 3  2 NA NA
  3 2  6  2 NA
  4 5  8  5  2
  5 1  3  6  3
  6 1  0  7  9
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Well, unfortunately it doesn't work exactly how it should. It doesn't take care of the panel structure, i.e. the lag's are shifted across cross-sections.
edit: I guess in combination with other functions of the dplyr I can solve the problem!

Comment: glad to hear it. if it's not meeting your use case in other ways please post desired output and im sure someone on SO can help out

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've already found a way, but I have to try it first. I need one more step in order to take care of the panel structure. Using your code doesn't do that and lags variables across cross-sections (which is no surprise, since the function doesn't know anything about the panel structure). I will use dplyr in combination with the group_by function in order to use model.frame for each group separately. That should do the trick. Thanks!